# Setting guard variables does not prevent default ftplugin/syntax/indent files from running

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, indentation, ftplugin

I want to prevent the default ftplugin/syntax/indent files from running for tex files.

I have a `tex.vim` in the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/ftplugin` directory, i confirmed it runs before the default ftplugin/syntax/indent files through `:scriptnames`, but the default ftplugin/syntax/indent files are still allowed to run unguarded, so for some reason the variables aren't actually being set.

the `tex.vim` file is as follows:

```
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
let b:current_syntax = "tex"
let b:did_indent = 1
```

I have also set `vim.g.tex_flavor = "latex"` in my `init.lua`, so it is defaulting to tex and not plaintex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the buffer is being reloaded after ftplugin, indent, syntax. So the buffer local variables aren't persistent.
Splitting the files into the correct ftplugin/syntax/indent dirs fixes the issues, but is somewhat verbose for just wanting to disable the defaults.